# When a prime ideal is a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a commutative ring with unit every maximal ideal is prime. Under what conditions does the converse occur?

Comment: You want to look at the literature on rings of "dimension zero". If the ring is Noetherian, then it is dimension zero iff it is Artinian.

Comment: If the ring R is a finite integral domain, then R is a field.

Answer (score 6):

When the ring has [Krull dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) equal to zero.  If we're talking about integral domains then every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal if and only if $R$ is a field (since $0$ is a prime ideal in any integral domain).

Comment: Possibly the questioner intended to exclude the $0$-ideal in case it is prime.

Comment: Possibly.  In that case, @Lmn6, you'll want to look at one-dimensional rings.  In the context of integral domains, the concepts of UFD and PID coincide.

Comment: @JackManey: what do you mean exactly with "in the contenxt of ID the concepts of UFD and PID coincide"?

Comment: @Lmn6 - If $R$ is an integral domain of Krull dimension at most 1, then $R$ is a UFD if and only if $R$ is a PID.

Answer (score 4):

When the ring contains no elements that are neither units nor zero divisors.  Irritatingly, I know of no short name for this third category of elements of rings.

Polynomials are a typical example:  Let $R$ be an integral domain and consider $R[x]$.  Polynomials (of positive degree) are not units (they don't have multiplicative inverses), nor are they zero divisors.  In such a ring, there are prime ideals that are not maximal ideals.  For instance $(x)$, which has $R[x]/(x) \cong R$.  Since $R$ had no zero divisors, neither does this quotient, so $(x)$ is prime.  However, unless $R$ was already a field, this quotient is not a field so $(x)$ is not maximal.

Comment: I am sorry to have revived this old thread, but I am curious as to how to prove such a ring necessarily have all its prime ideals being maximal. My own google search seems (to the best of my effort) to yield nothing on this. Although a chat in Discord claims it can be proved provided it has finite number of minimal prime ideals.

Comment: @Sampah : Quoting from the Answer: "In such a ring, there are prime ideals that are not maximal ideals.". Quoting from your comment "such a ring necessarily have all its prime ideals being maximal."  You ask about an occurrence that is not described in this Answer.

Answer (score -2):

A ring $R$ with identity is artinian if and only if it is noetherian and every prime ideal is a maximal ideal by Hopkins theorem.

Comment: Z is PID and noetherian but not artin